# Group by <a date field> is not working in my Sql (Oracle)

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to count the number of registrations done on each day of a given year(say, the reg table has first_name,last_name and reg_date as the columns).

This is what I am trying:

```
select reg_date, count(reg_date) 
from reg 
where reg_date >= to_date('01-JAN-12', 'DD-MON-YY') 
group by (reg_date)
```

The results are not as expected. It is not grouping by the reg_date and showing the registration date for each registration.

My reg_date has DATE type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is most probably because of the time part that every `DATE` carries. To get rid of it use the trunc function:

```
select trunc(reg_date), count(trunc(reg_date))
from reg 
where reg_date >= to_date('01-JAN-12', 'DD-MON-YY') 
group by trunc(reg_date)
```

Comment: Its funny how if you just run a trunc on the group by it still donest work...you have to run it on the actual select column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your date format to group by as well.

```
select count(1) aa, to_char(somedate, 'DD-MON-YY') bb
    from sometable
    group by to_char(somedate, 'DD-MON-YY')
    order by 2 asc;
```